# Regex: How not to match a few letters

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string: `SEE ATTACHED ADDENDUM TO HUD-1194,520.07`

Inside that string is `HUD-1` and after that is `194,520.07`. What I want is the `194,520.07` part.

I have written the following regular expression to pull that value out:

`[^D\-1](?:-|\()?\$?(?:\d{1,3}[ ,]?)*(?:\.\d+)\)?`

However, this pulls out: `94,520.07`

I know it has something to do with this part: `[^D\-1]` "eating" to many of the `1`'s. Any ideas how I can stop it from "eating" `1`'s after the first one that appears in `HUD-1`?

UPDATED:

The reason for all the other stuff is I only want to match as well if the value after HUD-1 is a money amount. And the rest of that regex tries to determine all the different ways a money amount could be written

Comment: `[^D\-1]` only eats at most one `1`. It must be one of the `\d` parts eating the subsequent one...

Comment: how general is your input? can you rely on there always being at D-1 before the number you want to match?

Comment: @PeterElliot Its not always there. It can be optional. Sometimes it will come in as SEE ATTACHED ADDENDUM 194,520.07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something as simple as:

```
.*HUD\-1(.*+)
```

Ok, you need to be more restrictive I see based on your updated question.  Try changing `[^D\-1]` to just `(?:HUD\-1)?`.  For what it's worth, your currency RegEx is vary lax, allowing input like:

> 001 001 .31412341234123

You might consider *not* reinventing the wheel there, I'm sure you can find a currency RegEx quickly via Google.  Otherwise, I'd also suggest anchoring your RegEx with a `$` at the end of it.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make this example simple. The reason for all the other stuff is I only want to match as well if the value after HUD-1 is a money amount. And the rest of that regex tries to determine all the different ways a money amount could be written.

Comment: Definitely information you need to include in your question.  Please update it and I'll update my answer.  3530 rep, you should know that.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

this change will make the second match group of the regex include the full number you would like (everything after the first 1), and put the possible HUD-1 in a separate matching group, if present.

```
(HUD-1)?((?:-|\()?\$?(?:\d{1,3}[ ,]?)*(?:\.\d+)\)?)
```